# Is there a method to override prop name in object with Ramda?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have this object`{thing1: {}, thing2: {}}` is there a method to override just a prop name like  `{thing1: {}, thing3not2: {}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a quicker/easier way, but you could combine `assoc` to add the new key and `dissoc` to remove the old key:

```js
const { curry, assoc, dissoc } = R;

const renameProp = curry(
  (oldName, newName, obj) =>
    dissoc(oldName, assoc(newName, obj[oldName], obj))
);
  
  
const myTransformation = renameProp("thing2", "thing3not2");

const myResult = myTransformation( {thing1: {}, thing2: {} } );

console.log(JSON.stringify(myResult, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ramda "cookbook" contains a `renameKeys` function
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#rename-keys-of-an-object

Below copied from there:

```
/**
 * Creates a new object with the own properties of the provided object, but the
 * keys renamed according to the keysMap object as `{oldKey: newKey}`.
 * When some key is not found in the keysMap, then it's passed as-is.
 *
 * Keep in mind that in the case of keys conflict is behaviour undefined and
 * the result may vary between various JS engines!
 *
 * @sig {a: b} -> {a: *} -> {b: *}
 */
const renameKeys = R.curry((keysMap, obj) =>
  R.reduce((acc, key) => R.assoc(keysMap[key] || key, obj[key], acc), {}, R.keys(obj))
);
```

And calling it

```
renameKeys({thing2: 'thing3not2'}, {thing1: {}, thing2: {}})
=> {"thing1": {}, "thing3not2": {}}
```